# Argument 'System.Action' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback'

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
WORKER CLASS1:

public override void Process(Crawler crawler, PropertyBag propertyBag)
            {
                SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
            }

            void ThreadFunc(object state)
            {
                var syncContext = state as SynchronizationContext;
                syncContext.Send(new Action(() => {
                    using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm ("http//www.google.com"))
                    {
                        geckoBrowserForm.ShowDialog();

                        while (!geckoBrowserForm.Done)
                        {
                           Application.DoEvents();
                        }

                        other code
                    }
                }), null);  
            }
```

But I Always get

> "Argument 'System.Action' is not assignable to parameter type
>   'System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback'"

I want that every `Process` will have own `SynchronizationContext` and then execute UIS Thread with some logic.

```
UI THREAD CLASS2:

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  String val = "Some value";
  Done = true;
  and return back `val` to the `CLASS1` 
}
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public virtual void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)

public delegate void SendOrPostCallback(Object state)
```

Clearly, the `Send` method takes a delegate with an `object` parameter and `void` return value. You are passing a delegate without a parameter. Try

```
syncContext.Send(new Action(o => { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SendOrPostCallback() lambda needs to take one parameter of object type. See [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.sendorpostcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try changing your call to this (note the lambda changed to `(o)` from `()`):

```
syncContext.Send(new Action((o) => {
    using (GeckoBrowserForm geckoBrowserForm = new GeckoBrowserForm ("http//www.google.com"))
        {
            geckoBrowserForm.ShowDialog();

            while (!geckoBrowserForm.Done)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            // other code
        }
    }), null);
```